# File Picker not working, also camera not opening in webview

Tags: file, android-webview, android-camera, picker

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        Uri[] results = null;
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == asw_file_req) {
                if (null == CAMERA_SERVICE) {
                    return;
                }
                if (intent == null || intent.getData() == null) {
                    if (asw_cam_message != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(CAMERA_SERVICE)};
                    }
                } else {
                    String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{ Uri.parse(dataString) };
                    } else {
                        if(ASWP_MULFILE) {
                            if (intent.getClipData() != null) {
                                final int numSelectedFiles = intent.getClipData().getItemCount();
                                results = new Uri[numSelectedFiles];
                                for (int i = 0; i < numSelectedFiles; i++) {
                                    results[i] = intent.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        asw_file_path.onReceiveValue(results);
        asw_file_path = null;
    } else {
        if (requestCode == asw_file_req) {
            if (null == asw_file_message) return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
            asw_file_message.onReceiveValue(result);
            asw_file_message = null;
        }
    }

}

@SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("READ_PERM =",Manifest.permission.CAMERA );
    Log.w("READ_PERM = ",Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    Log.w("WRITE_PERM = ",Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    Log.w(TAG, "onPermissionRequest");


    //Prevent the app from being started again when it is still alive in the background
    if (!isTaskRoot()) {
        finish();
        return;
    }

    asw_view = findViewById(R.id.msw_view);

    //Webview settings; defaults are customized for best performance
    WebSettings webSettings = asw_view.getSettings();

    if(!ASWP_OFFLINE){
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(ASWP_JSCRIPT);
    }
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(ASWP_SFORM);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(ASWP_ZOOM);
    webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(ASWP_LOCATION);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.getMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture();

    asw_view.setDownloadListener((url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimeType, contentLength) -> {

        if(!check_permission(2)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, file_perm);
        }else {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

            request.setMimeType(mimeType);
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            request.setDescription(getString(R.string.dl_downloading));
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            assert dm != null;
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.dl_downloading2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    asw_view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

                                    /**
                                     * @param acceptType
                                     * @param capture
                                     */
                                    //Handling input[type="file"] requests for android API 16+
                                    private void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
                                        if(ASWP_FUPLOAD) {
                asw_file_message = uploadMsg;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("images/*");
                if(ASWP_MULFILE) {
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                }
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.fl_chooser)), asw_file_req);
            }
        }
```

While pressing camera button camera not opening in webview.
Here are the screen shots

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.